# Unable to open json file as it exceeds the 5 MB limit for the JSON editor

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

For my Windows 8.1 universal app, my source data stored in JSon file exceeds the 5MB limit for the JSON editor and therefore my app fails to initialize. Now I cannot run both my Windows phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 app. Also, now when I open my JSON file for editing, the VS 2013 JSON editor does not allow me to add more data to it. Anyone encountered this issue before? Any idea on how to increase the 5MB limit, or split the file into multiple files, and yet let the application use it as one big JSon file?

Comment: How is this related to windows phone? Do you have troubles processing the file in you app?

Comment: Yes, it is related to Windows phone 8.1 as I am using the same file as shared data for Windows phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1. There is no trouble processing the file as long as I keep its size to less than 5MB. However, for file size  greater than 5 MB, the app fails to initialize.

Comment: What is failing exactly? What code are you using to load the json file? What exception is being thrown?

Comment: There is no exception. There is no issue with the code used to load the json file. Everything was working fine until I added more content to the json file, which makes it more than 5 MB size. Now, when I open the json file in the JSON editor, it shows the message "Unable to open json file as it exceeds the 5MB limit for the JSON editor" and when I run the the application, it fails to initialize. If I reduce the content to keep the file size less than 5 MB, the apps works perfectly.

Comment: Is JSON produced by VS editor valid or is it e.g. cut at some point? If it isn't able to pass 5MB limit try another editor.

Answer (score 0):

Added the feedback about this issue to Microsoft Connect feedback portal: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/1465015/unable-to-open-json-file-as-it-exceeds-the-5-mb-limit-for-the-json-edito.

Looks like this is an VS issue. VS does have a 5MB limit on Json file size. See the related thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c3ecf2b2-ab00-4983-8c81-cd33e35ee4c2/unable-to-open-json-file-as-it-exceeds-the-5-mb-limit-for-the-json-editor?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: Is this issue resolved.. I still get error when loading JSON files greater than 5 MB.. Out of memory exception..